# wso2-Connecting to aws s3

Tags: wso2

Error while connecting wso2 to AWS s3.we are getting 'sequence template-get object' not found error. Kindly help. we are trying to connect through amazon connector. whatever mediator we are trying to use it says sequence template not found.

connection to s3 and retrieve objects

Comment: Did you package the connector to the CApp using a Connector Exporter Project? Refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/creating-artifacts/adding-connectors/#packaging-connectors